# mediaPlayer starts and stops at 5 seconds for 10 seconds

Tags: android, service

mediaPlayer starts and stops at 5 seconds for 10 seconds and then continues playing

Why is this? Why load the buffer? but if so, shouldn't it load at first?
Because literally, when you press play, after 5 seconds it starts but then after 5 seconds it stops for 10 and then continues without problems.

Is there any way to not do this? or am i doing something wrong? below the code:

```
public class ForegroundService extends Service {
    public static final String CHANNEL_ID = "ForegroundServiceChannel";

    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        String url = "https://xxxxxx:xxxx"; // the URL 
        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        try {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        String input = intent.getStringExtra("inputExtra");
        createNotificationChannel();
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, Principal.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
                0, notificationIntent, 0);

        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                .setContentTitle("FM UNIVERSIDAD")
                .setContentText(input)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icono)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .build();

        startForeground(1, notification);
   

        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener(){
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer player) {
                // Called when the MediaPlayer is ready to play
                mediaPlayer.start();
            }
        }); // Set callback for when prepareAsync() finishes

        mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();

        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
       mediaPlayer.stop();
        mediaPlayer.reset();
        mediaPlayer.release();
        mediaPlayer = null;



    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    private void createNotificationChannel() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel serviceChannel = new NotificationChannel(
                    CHANNEL_ID,
                    "Foreground Service Channel",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
            );

            NotificationManager manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            manager.createNotificationChannel(serviceChannel);
        }
    }


    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    private void initMediaSession(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {

        mMediaSession = new MediaSession(this, "MEDIA_SESSION_TAG");
        mMediaSession.setCallback(new MediaSession.Callback() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMediaButtonEvent(Intent mediaButtonIntent) {
                // Consume the media button event here. Should not send it to other apps.
                return true;
            }
        });

        mMediaSession.setFlags(MediaSession.FLAG_HANDLES_MEDIA_BUTTONS |
                MediaSession.FLAG_HANDLES_TRANSPORT_CONTROLS);

        if (!mMediaSession.isActive()) {
            mMediaSession.setActive(true);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you considered using something else for playback, such as ExoPlayer?

Comment: Yes I did and I also used to use Exoplayer but this time It can not reproduces it because is a mpeg stream format.